# Troubleshooting "unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE" when calling mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

I've made this simple logout script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$db_connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '*****');
    if(!$db_connect)
        {
         die('Не може да се осъществи връзка с базата данни' . mysql_error());
        }
mysql_select_db("chat", $db_connect);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM activeusers WHERE au_id = '$_SESSION['UserId']'");
mysql_close($db_connect);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

But when I put `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` at the end my editor shows an error with the `mysql_query` I haven't tried this yet but I think that probably written this way I empty the $_SESSION array() and thus `$_SESSION['UserId']` is destroyed before the query.Am I right here and how should I do it right?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\Program Files\webPHP\xampp\htdocs\MyChat\logout.php on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your `mysql_query`-command like this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM activeusers WHERE au_id = '".$_SESSION['UserId']."'");
```

This makes sure it is properly embedded into the SQL-part of the command.

Answer (score 1):

change your query to:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM activeusers WHERE au_id = '".$_SESSION['UserId']."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inline the variable in the string, you should do one of these:

```
// Enclose the variable in curly braces:
mysql_query("DELETE FROM activeusers WHERE au_id = '{$_SESSION['UserId']}'");

// Remove quotes from the element name:
mysql_query("DELETE FROM activeusers WHERE au_id = '$_SESSION[UserId]'");
```

See http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing for more information on how PHP interprets variables in strings.